# forms authentication with sql server 2008 database questions

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Hello I been trying to figure out how to set up ASP.Net forms authentication with sql database I have been trying to figure out how to set up my forms authentication with my sql database. So when I update my admin table it also updates the admin list in the forms authentication.

Any ideas would help thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run the aspnet_regsql.exe tool and the membership database will be created for you. If you run it without any parameters, it will present you with a wizard to guide you through the database creation process.

Here's an example of what you need to add to your Web.Config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="50000000"/>
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
        applicationName="/" 
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
        enablePasswordReset="true" 
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
        requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
        passwordFormat="Hashed" 
        minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
        name="SqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Also note that you can perform all configuration (except the provider) using the [ASP.NET WAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228053.aspx) (Web Site Administration Tool) from withing Visual Studio.

Here's a walk-through of the entire process:

[Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx)

Comment: thank you however i was wondering how would you add new member in sql database with out using asp.net confi would you do it in ado?

Comment: Use the WAT tool icon at the top right of solution explorer in VS :) Then it's GUI driven for this - you can further tweak setting in the secure folder Web.Config file(s) it generates.

Comment: thank you! question i have a databse of username and password how would i use the asp.net forms register page to add admin instead of adding each admin one at a time thank you.

Comment: Do something like this (though I do not advise it unless you have a lot of admins) http://forums.asp.net/t/1259172.aspx/1