# How to enable .NET roles section in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm watching a training video and they are showing how to add Roles using .NET Roles section in IIS.  I don't see that section in my IIS 7. I'm guessing I need to enable it somewhere. How  do I make .NET Roles show on in IIS?

**update:** There is also .NET Users and .NET Profiles section that is not visible. These are related so I think whatever enables Roles will enable the rest.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you use the same operating system like the trainer. Different OS ships with different icon sets, and there is little you can do to add/remove icons.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WSAT tool - the icon should be at the top of your Solution Explorer window in VS.

Also check similar question here:

[forms authentication with sql server 2008 database questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901819/forms-authentication-with-sql-server-2008-database-questions/9901945#9901945)

Comment: The ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool allows you to view and manage your Web site configuration through a simple Web interface.  I've done this before using Web Site Admin. It is a valid workaround, however, I'm still curious as to how to do it in IIS without going the website.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know; I've never used IIS to manage users/roles.

Comment: Weird thing is I cannot even get to the ".NET Roles Pane", which is where you want to get to in IIS7 to do what you want to do :/