# Using a new / separate database for forms authentication

Tags: sql-server, forms-authentication

Does anyone have a view on whether to use a new separate database for forms authentication users, or is it ok to mix it with your application database?

I could see separation being useful if multiple applications/databases were sharing user authentication, but in my case I have one website/database, and intended to just add the tables/views/sps created by aspnet_regsql.exe to my current application database.

Any views/opinions welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix that db with your database BUT you should not make any changes to the default database tables if you want to use asp.net built in classes that use that database , It means you can only add your tables to that database !

Answer (score 0):

That is OK to have a single Database from which the Forms are to be authenticated. Since the SQL server is a very secure one there will be no problem in having a single database.

But If you want to setup Your custom database for Authentication then Refer the following Links

[Using Forms Authentication with a customer database](http://forums.asp.net/t/1802941.aspx/1)

[forms authentication with sql server 2008 database questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901819/forms-authentication-with-sql-server-2008-database-questions)